# Notepad++ CS Script loop through lines and change particular values

Tags: notepad++

I haven’t used CS Script with Notepad++ before but I am working on several large files where I need to create a script.
I normally work in excel and use VBasic but the files are too big for excel.
I have installed CS Script and created the script page but don’t know anything about the code so could really do with some help.
Below is an example of the lines in the files I have.

```
1.  699;2022-06-30 18:44:03.187;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;15.9371195;15.9371194999999997;0.000
2.  699;2022-06-30 18:45:03.179;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;16.183062;0.245942499999999953;59.992
3.  699;2022-06-30 18:46:03.173;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;16.315498;0.132436000000001997;59.994
4.  699;2022-06-30 18:47:03.169;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;16.40275;0.0872519999999994411;59.996
5.  699;2022-06-30 18:48:03.163;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;16.469275;0.066524999999998613;59.994
6.  699;2022-06-30 18:49:03.154;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;16.428036;-0.0412390000000009138;59.991
7.  699;2022-06-30 18:50:03.152;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;16.565973;0.137937000000000864;59.998
```

The columns in excel are separated by `;`. I want to start at the second line and loop through every line to the end of the file.

On each line it should check if the number in the second last column (i.e. before the last `;`) is negative. If it isn’t it just moves to the next line. If it is negative it should change the numbers in the last three columns `0` .

So based on my example above it would change line 6 to what I have shown below. All the other lines would remain the same.

```
6.  699;2022-06-30 18:49:03.154;1.1.8;2409;Line_1_IP_Router:0/1/0;w;0;0;0
```

I hope this all makes sense and would really appreciate anyone’s help. I’m sure it is fairly basic code for someone familiar with CS Script.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use CS script? This could be done with a regular expression search/replace. In the text of the question I don't see how the modification is *based on criteria in previous line* as mentioned in the title.

Comment: Hi Bodo, there is no requirement to use CS script as long as I achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Sorry I also forgot to say on your second point I changed the criteria when writing the question to make it easier to explain but forgot to change the title. Originally I was basing it on the third last column and if the number in the previous line was higher. Both achieve the exact same thing but I felt what I put up was easier to explain but I neglected to edit the question title.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to fix the title. A method to replace values as specified in the question might not work if the replacement needs to be based on the previous line. Please specify in the question if you can use `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know CS script, but this can be done using the standard search/replace operation (CTRL+H) with regular expression

search for `;[0-9.]*;-[0-9.]*;[0-9.]*$` and replace with `;0;0;0`.

**Explanation:** `[0-9.]*` searches for any number (even 0) of characters from the range `0`-`9` or `.`, `$` matches the end of the line. The pattern would also match lines ending with e.g.

```
;;-;
;1.2.3;-4..5;6....7
```

[image: screenshot]

If the real requirement is to replace data in one line based on the values of the previous line, it will be more difficult.

Comment: Brilliant thank you I will try that